# Oxford comma with nonessential phrases

Tags: phrases, commas, lists, oxford-comma

So, I've got the following list containing a nonessential phrase ("ultimately"), non-Oxford comma:

> stifling curiosity, creativity and, ultimately, progress.

Is it then correct, when converted to an Oxford comma, to end up with this monstrosity?

> stifling curiosity, creativity, and, ultimately, progress.

Comment: It is at *The New Yorker* and other publications. This is a matter of style, and there is no "correct" style.

Comment: I can't see why you think that "ultimately" is a clause. I'd say it was an adverb phrase.

Comment: @Robusto: I didn't mean correct as in Correct, I meant in the context of oxford comma style.

Comment: @BillJ: you're right. Corrected the question title, body, and tags.

Comment: @Toothrot: if it's nonessential then there should be a comma around, no?

Comment: As usual, there exists in these areas a point beyond which trying to force a convention to hold (or to pursue an analysis using existing terminology) becomes nonsensical. '... stifling curiosity, creativity, and, ultimately, progress' doesn't conform to the minimalist (subject to reasonable clarity) trend in punctuation nowadays. '... stifling curiosity, creativity, and ultimately progress' looks far better. Even if it doesn't conform to the third law of wiggleuse.

Comment: Of course, with adverbs you need the/a verb to understand the phrase: For example: [They demonstrated] stifling curiosity, creativity and, ultimately, progress. "ultimately" goes with the verb. In this particular case, setting the word "ultimately" off by commas cannot be called use of the Oxford comma. Here's another one: They lacked conventional manners,sensible attitudes and, ironically, a sense of humor. I sincerely doubt any editor would disagree with that. As for Oxford commas,let's do it: They adored apples, oranges, bananas, and, funnily enough, coconuts.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with this clash of conventions, you could change something.  "stifling curiosity, creativity, and (ultimately) progress."

Comment: I don't know the names of the conventions, but using alternate delimiters is valid. One version I was taught would have you upgrade the Oxford commas to semi colons, there. "...curiosity; creativity; and, ultimately, progress." Another would have you leave the commas off that "ultimately". Yet another would use dashes for it. That is probably what I'd do. "...creativity, and--ultimately--progress."

Comment: @TheNate "_creativity, and -- ultimately -- progress_" looks like a winner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You are applying two distinct comma guidelines consistently:

- The commas around a nonessential element. (Purdue OWL [has some examples](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/commas_with_nonessential_elements.html).)
- Commas (including the serial comma) separating items in a list of three or more elements. ([Number 5](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html) in this list.)

There is no standard guideline for what to do if the application of multiple rules leads to a clusterfudge of commas. Whether you would rephrase or omit the serial comma in your example is an editorial decision. I'd suggest rephrasing if I have a stylistic concern. However, the New Yorker wouldn't; in an article entitled "[In Defense of 'Nutty Commas](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/in-defense-of-nutty-commas),'" they justify both the use of the serial comma and a low hurdle for considering something a nonessential element. So they have:

> “I invited my boss, her nephew, and my acupuncturist to the party.” (straightforward serial comma example)
>
> “Before Atwater died, of brain cancer, in 1991, he expressed regret …” ("of brain cancer, in 1991" is treated as a pair of nonessential elements)

Whatever you choose, be consistent.

Comment: They disliked relevant examples, sample sentences and, mostly, disagreement of any kind. :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a situation that there are any prescribed rules for to my knowledge. You'll have to make a decision and apply it consistently. My opinion on the matter is that you should ignore the commas around non-essential phrases rule in this case. In my opinion

> stifling curiosity, creativity, and ultimately, progress.

is superior to the two forms in your question. Because the stifling of progress is implied to be a result of the stifling of curiosity and creativity, I think it would also be appropriate to say:

> stifling curiosity and creativity, and, ultimately, progress.